# Issue about transaction in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, transactions

I have 2 models: modelA, modelB. I want to implement 2 operations which are related to these models in the CI's transaction in myController. E.x:

```
$this->db->trans_start();

$this->modelA->uodateA(conditions, item);
$this->modelB->updateB(conditions, item);
// with conditions and item is valid
$this->db->trans_complete();

if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
{
//handle when failed
}
```

Here is 2 operation in these models:

```
public function updateA($where = array(), $item = array(), $auth = NULL){
        if(!is_array($item) && empty($item)) return FALSE;

        if(is_numeric($where)){
            $where = array('vote_id'=>$where);
        }
        $this->db->where($where)->update($this->_table,$item);


        return    ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0);
    }


public function updateB($where = array(), $item = array(), $auth = NULL){
        if(!is_array($item) && empty($item)) return FALSE;

            if(is_numeric($where)){
                $where = array('vote_id'=>$where);
            }

        $this->db->where($where)->update($this->_table,$item);
        return ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0);
    }
```

Although updateB() is failed (Ex: can't have record to update, update int field with string value...) but trans_status() still return true. I want when updateB() is failed it must be rollback. How to fix? Thanks so much

Comment: Can you post your model codes too?

Comment: As long as you don't have other transaction statements in your model methods, your sample code should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
 $this->db->trans_begin();

 $this->modelA->insertA();
 $this->modelB->updateB();

 if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
 {
    $this->db->trans_rollback();
 }
 else
 {
    $this->db->trans_commit();
 }
```

Comment: You should write above code in a single model. Can you post your both queries? it will help us to rectify.

Comment: I think none of your queries going to execute because you are not passing any paramters,As per your logic you have written function will return false always .  Also if you declaring  variable $where as array then why you need to check  if(is_numeric($where)){....